# How to write correctly a program which extract all links from a web page?

Tags: python, web-crawler, extract

This is the part of Udacity course WEB SEARCH ENGINE.The goal of this quiz is to write a program which extract all links from the web page.On the output program must return only LINKS.But in my case program  returns all links and "NONE" twice.I know that the error in the second part of program after "WHILE" and after "ELSE".But i dont know what i must write there.

```
def get_next_target(page):
  start_link = page.find('<a href=')
  if start_link == -1:
    return None,0

  else:
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    endquo = page.find('"',start_quote + 1)
    url = page[(start_quote + 1) : endquo]
    return url,endquo 

page = 'i know what you  doing summer <a href="Udasity".i know what you  doing summer <a href="Georgia" i know what you  doing summer '


def ALLlink(page):
  url = 1
  while url != None:
    url,endquo = get_next_target(page)
    if url:
      print url
      page = page[endquo:] 
    else:

print ALLlink(page)
```

Comment: Does this code run, if not (what I assume), what is the error message. I'd guess it points you to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can remove your `else` statement in your `ALLlink()` function since it's not doing anything.

Also, when comparing to `None`, you should use `is not` instead of `!=`:

```
while url != None:  # bad
while url is not None  # good
```

That said, I think your error is in your last line:

`print ALLlink(page)`

You basically have two print statements. The first is inside your function and the second is on the last line of your script. Really, you don't need the last print statement there because you're already printing in your `ALLlink()` function. So if you change the line to just `ALLlink(page)`, I think it'll work.

If you do want to print there, you could modify your function to store the URLs in an array, and then print that array. Something like this:

```
def ALLlink(page):
    urls = []
    url = 1
    while url is not None:
        url, endquo = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            urls.append(url)
            page = page[endquo:]
    return urls

print ALLlink(page)
```